# Outlook add in not registering for all users

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

i have created an outlook add in and a setup project for that add in using VS setup. I have changed the properties of the setup project "InstallAllUsers" as true.

It successfully generates the .msi and .exe file.
I run the .exe file or .msi as admin an the add in is registered for a single user only. registry entry is only visible in the HKCU hive not in the HKLM hive.

I am on windows 8.1 , Office 2013.

cheers,

Saurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have changed the properties of the setup project "InstallAllUsers" as true.

The **InstallAllUsers** property doesn't affect the registry hive where the add-in is registered. You need to choose an appropriate windows registry hive manually.

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article describes all the required steps for creating an MSI installed for Office add-ins (including per-machine).

Comment: thanks again... i followed the steps and was able to do achieve my requirements...but this was using Install Shield where i used the UI to create the registry...how about doing this from the normal vs installer ?